# Can not find the property Featured of undefined in Ionic 3

Tags: html, angular, ionic3

I am working on Ionic framework. I have fetching the JSON from an API. I have successfully fetched all the data but the problem is , when I am trying to show it on my page, then it is giving an error of `Can not read property **Featured** of undefined`.

My Featured.ts is:

```
import { ApiProvider } from './../../providers/api/api';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-featured',
  templateUrl: 'featured.html',
})
export class FeaturedPage {
  videos: Observable<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public apiProvider: ApiProvider) { 
    this.videos = this.apiProvider.getVideos();
     this.videos
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log('my data: ', data);
    })
  }
}
```

My `Featured.html` is:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>My First List</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
  hey
    <h1 ion-item *ngFor="let fetch of videos.data.featured" >
      <ion-icon name="{{item.icon}}" item-left></ion-icon>
      {{fetch.category_name}}
      <div class="item-note" item-right>
        <youtube-player
                        content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;"
                        [videoId]="fetch.video_id_" (ready)="savePlayer($event)"
                        (change)="onStateChange($event)"></youtube-player>
      </div>
    </h1>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

My JSON is:

```
{
    "api_status": "200",
    "api_version": "1.0",
    "data": {
        "featured": [{
            "id": 254,
            "video_id": "hsIL3Lgshbmh3sP",
            "user_id": 13,
            "title": "Dear Future Generations: Sorry | by Prince ea",
            "description": "Dear Future Generations: Sorry | by Prince ea <br>The sole purpose of this inspirational video is to raise awareness about the alarming rates of deforestation and the reckless destruction of our environment for which we all are responsible. This video tries to inspire the people of this world that immediate action must be taken to stop the destruction of the forests and to bring mainstream attention to this issue. This video teaches us that it is up to us to take care of this planet, it is our only home. To betray nature is to betray us, to save nature is to save us. Nothing will matter at last because if we don&#039;t work together to save the environment, we will be equally extinct. <br>Prince Ea, an activist, and inspirational spoken word artist has done it again this is one of the most powerful videos I have ever seen about mitigating climate change.",
            "thumbnail": "https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/eRLJscAlk1M\/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "video_location": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=eRLJscAlk1M",
            "youtube": "eRLJscAlk1M",
            "vimeo": "",
            "daily": "",
            "time": 1529352372,
            "time_date": "2018-06-18 20:06:12",
            "active": 0
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need set `data` to `this.videos` not subcriber itself:

in your typescript:

```
this.apiProvider.getVideos()
.subscribe(data => {
    this.videos = data;
     console.log('my data: ', data);
})
```

Now in your html for loop like this:

```
*ngFor="let fetch of videos?.data?.featured"
```

hope this helps!!!

Comment: sorry but not a good idea. It clear the errors on console, but will not eliminate them.

Comment: @NSharma  call async pipe  `(videos | async)?.data?.featured`

Answer (score 0):

try changing this

```
this.videos = this.apiProvider.getVideos();
     this.videos
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log('my data: ', data);
    })
```

to

```
this.apiProvider.getVideos().subscribe(data => {
this.videos = data;          
console.log('my data: ', data);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

> ts file code

```
videos:any;
this.apiProvider.getVideos().subscribe(data => {
    this.videos = data;
     console.log('my data: ', data);
})
```

> html file code

```
*ngFor="let fetch of videos?.data?.featured"
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not a right approach. It just clear the errors on console.

Comment: Please be aware that using the elvis operator (?) as Krishna suggests _is_ the right approach (at least partly), because for a certain time, before the api completes, `this.videos` ***has  no value*** and therefore you must guard against evaluation of `data.featured` when data is undefined - as your error message is telling you.

Comment: The other thing that Krishna recommends is to change videos to be non-observable, and set it in the subscribe - is probably the best way to go. Otherwise you need to use the async pipe as suggested in other comments.